# Why I don's see simple app in Firefox OS emulator?

Tags: firefox-os, web-ide

I created a new sample project in WebIDE and don't see this project, when run emulator.

What could be the cause of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you pressed the "play" button to push the app to the emulator?

Comment: I had not choose runtime, so Play Button was disabled.

Comment: Gotcha. I added your suggestion/issue as a bug. Thanks! https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1162984

Answer (score 0):

Install a runtime.Choose a simulator version and install it.Click on the play button Then you will be able to run it.